# how to embed and share MP3 file?

Tags: asp.net, html, mp3, embed

I've got a my own website and I've put on my website a radio interview (MP3 file). On my website there is a tool which takes the MP3 file and plays it.

My file URL is  "http://www.abc.com/invterview/July 9 interview.MP3"

Now, another website wants to play the same file and asks me to give te embed/share link.

Can someone help me how to accomplish this link?

I googled and found this webpage http://www.labnol.org/internet/design/html-embed-mp3-songs-podcasts-music-in-blogs-websites/2232/ ,which explains how to accomplish an EMBED, but I've never done this and I know Chrome, IE, FF, Safari have it's own instructions...

So can someone guide me how to accomplish an EMBED URL so it will work on all Browser?
Do I need to use  or  what is the common use??????

if it was video file I could upload it to Youtube and send that link, but this is a MP3 file.

thanks

Comment: A quick Google search throws up a few options - some using Flash, some not. e.g. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/embed-mp3-player-website/

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTML5, which has native support for playing audio.

```
<audio controls="controls" height="100" width="100">
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<embed height="100" width="100" src="song.mp3" />
</audio>
```

If a browser does not support HTML5, the code above will fallback to the embed code.

Other than that, you could use the yahoo media player. It's not the coolest or best around, but it's simple and it gets the job done.

```
<a href="song.mp3">Play Song</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/js">
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the link below, it shows the picture, but it doesn't play? 

<audio width="350" height="50" controls="controls" /><source type="audio/mp3" src="http://www.abc.com/Portals/0/CISSFlashPlayers/Files/2012 July Interview MPEG Layer 3 Audio/2012 July Interview MPEG Layer 3 Audio.mp3" /><source type="audio/ogg" src="/Portals/0/song.ogg" /><embed width="350" height="50" src="/Portals/0/song.mp3" />

Comment: Have your tried to escape the special chars in your URL? e.g. replace the spaces with %20 ...

Comment: OK it works now... So what code  do I need to send to the Other website so they can embed the link? the tag <audio> ????

Comment: You need to send them everything from <a href="yourmp3.mp3">... down to the </script>

Remember to put http://www.yourdomain.com/mp3filename.mp3 as your source - Otherwise it will try to stream from their own site, and won't find the mp3 file.

Comment: so the question is then Why do I need to send them HTML TAG like EMbed etc... I will send them like this then : http://www.abc.com/mp3/interview.mp3.... so why to send them the embed/object etc... ???? why would just the mp3-file address not be enough?

Comment: You stated that they asked for the embed code. But if they have their own streaming solution / media player, the URL for the mp3 file should be enough. You could just include both - That way you'll be pretty sure it'll work.